# Spring Webflux, log response body from reactive http request only in debug mode

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Small question regarding how to log response body from HTTP request sent from a Webflux Webclient, but **only in debug mode** please.

Currently, in the app, I am making reactive http outbound calls this way:

```
webClient.mutate()
         .baseUrl(someURL)
         .build()
         .post()
         .uri(someRoute)
         .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(myRequest))
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

This is working fine.
However, sometimes, there are issues, and I would like to see the response body for debugging.

Therefore, I took the *wrong* decision to use .log()

```
webClient.mutate()
         .baseUrl(someURL)
         .build()
         .post()
         .uri(someRoute)
         .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(myRequest))
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToMono(String.class)
         .log();
```

And this is great, I was able to see some logs, it resemble to something like this:

```
[ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.LiftFuseable.1              : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] ScopePassingSpanSubscriber)
[ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.LiftFuseable.1              : | request(unbounded)
[ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.LiftFuseable.1              : | onNext({foo='bar'})
[ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.LiftFuseable.1              : | onComplete()
```

However, I am now logging this no matter the log level...

No matter the level I set using `logging.level.root=DEBUG`  I am always seeing the logs now.

May I ask how to achieve this, but for debug log level only please? I am looking at the API, and it seems .log() can take parameter, but I am not able to make it work only for debug.

Or maybe some other ways to achieve logging response body only at debug level would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally tack on the `log()` based on logging level (or some other profile/environment indicator).

```java
Mono<String> makeCall(final WebClient webClient, final ?? myRequest) { 
   final Mono<String> response = webClient.mutate()
                                          .baseUrl(someURL)
                                          .build()
                                          .post()
                                          .uri(someRoute)
                                          .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(myRequest))
                                          .retrieve()
                                          .bodyToMono(String.class);

    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        return response.log();
    }
    return response;
}
```